# Updating 3 million rows in file geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, cursor, performance

I have a GDB which has 3 million annotation data, then I would like to modify some filed values based on csv table

I'm using the following ArcPy scripts now, but it's too slow

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

path = r"C:\test.gdb\ANNO"
csv = pd.read_csv("new.csv")

for index, row in csv.iterrows():
    expression = 'FCODE in {0}'.format(row['CODE'])
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(path, ["AnnotationClassID","SymbolID"],where_clause=expression) as cursor: 
        for row1 in cursor:
            row1[0] = row['AID']
            row1[1] = row['AID']
            cursor.updateRow(row1)
print('ok')
```

The contents of this csv table look like this:

| AID | CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ('111','222') |
| 2 | ('333','444') |
| 3 | ('555','666') |

**Additional Information**

1. I am using ArcPy with ArcMap, and this dataset is stored on the SSD.
2. This is a standalone script, running in Python IDLE.
3. I’ve tried using the Calculate Field tool from ArcPy, but it takes more than twice as long as UpdateCursor method.

Now it takes about seven hours. Is there any way to speed up the processing?

Comment: Is this datset on a USB 2.0 thumb drive? Mounted through a satellite link? If it's not on a local high-performace device (e.g., SSD) then you need to [[Edit] the Question to report the architecture of your configuration.

Comment: Have you tried using the Calculate Field tool from ArcPy?

Comment: What is `table` set to?  Is there anything else besides setting that and `import arcpy` that you do before the code that you've presented?

Comment: And do you have an index on FCODE? Even with 3M rows, loading the CSV data to a dictionary and making one update pass would probably be faster (on the order of seconds, not hours\)

Comment: You are instantiating an update cursor within a loop, which is definitely not a good approach when looping over hundreds or more items.

Comment: Have you added an attribute indices to the fields you are querying against? That will improve performance.

Answer (score -2):

Try Using Python Ecosystem Libraries, Like:

1. [Geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/)
2. [SpatialPandas](https://pypi.org/project/spatialpandas/)